# WPGrabber Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Настраиваю парсинг новостей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняю тест импорта, получаю следующие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://tsn.ua/ru/ukrayina/v-kieve-proshla-akcii-v-podderzhku-golodovki-advokata-semey-nebesnoy-sotni-1449768.html (178 Байт) **текст не найден!**

В чем моя ошибка, что делаю не правильно?

Comment: Все картинки должны быть в теле вопроса.

Comment: редирект на https не срабатывает